# Cannot find webelement using Selenium if they are dynamic

Tags: java, selenium, dynamic, selenium-webdriver

I'm having difficulties in locating a web element in seleniumn the html is as follows:

```
<div class="d2l-fieldgroup">
<div class=" vui-field-row">
<span class="d2l-field vui-label d2l-offscreen">Do not ask me again for this application</span>
<label class="d2l-checkbox-container">
<input name="dontAsk" value="0" type="hidden">
<input id="dontAsk" class="d2l-checkbox vui-input vui-outline" type="checkbox">
Do not ask me again for this application
</label>
</div>
</div>
```

I need to click on the checkbox or text but I just cant seem to be able to do this as I always get an error back saying:

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector"
```

I tried this:

```
WebElement do_not_ask_resourcebank = driver.findElement(By.className("d2l-fieldgroup"));
do_not_ask_resourcebank.click();
```

But get the following error:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"d2l-fieldgroup"}
```

I also tried replacing d2l-fieldgroup with vui-field-row and d2l-checkbox-container

I also tried:

```
WebElement do_not_ask_resourcebank = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html/body/form/div/div[3]/div/label"));
```

and

```
WebElement do_not_ask_resourcebank = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('confirmForm')/x:div/x:div[3]/x:div/x:label"));
```

but I just cannot seem to click on this element,  very frustrating for a newbie like myself.  Can someone point me to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `NoSuchElementException` as your provided exception, There may be following reasons :-

- May be you are locating with incorrect locator, you're locating actually `<div>` element with class name which looks like dynamically generated class name instead of actual `<input type = 'checkbox'>` element which you want. And other also looks unstable, You should try to locate desire element using `By.id()` as :-

  ```
  WebElement do_not_ask_resourcebank = driver.findElement(By.id("dontAsk"));
  ```
- May be when you are going to find element, it would not be present on the `DOM`, So you should implement `WebDriverWait` to wait until element visible as below :-

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("dontAsk")));
  ```
- May be this element is inside any `frame` or `iframe`. If it is, you need to switch that `frame` or `iframe` before finding the element as below :-

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

  //Find frame or iframe and switch
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("your frame id or name"));

  //Now find the element 
  WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("dontAsk")));

  //Once all your stuff done with this frame need to switch back to default
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  ```

**Edited** :

> I havent tried the iframe yet because I am not sure what I am doing I havent used this tool much. The html code for the iframe is : `<iframe id="d2l_1_69_954" class="d2l-iframe d2l-iframe-fullscreen d2l_1_67_746" name="d2l_1_69_954" src="/d2l/lms/remoteplugins/lti/launchLti.d2l?ou=6606&plugin‌​Id=f8acc58b-c6d5-42d‌​f-99d9-e334f825c011&‌​d2l_body_type=3" title="TALLPOD" scrolling="auto" allowfullscreen="" onload="this.m_loaded=true;" style="height: 314px;" frameborder="0">` how do you locate this iframe using your example above?

Looks like `iframe` `id` and `name` both are dynamically generated which could be change every time when you locate, you should try to locate this `iframe` with unique locator, I think it's `title name` is unique and fixed so you should try to locate this `iframe` before locating desired element as :-

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe[title='TAFEPOC']"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  You make a good point about it not being on the DOM..  I added : `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` and tried to use the :  `driver.findElement(By.id("dontAsk")).click();`  unfortunatley it still cant locate it.  I also tried:  `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='confirmForm']")).click();`  after inspecting the XPath with FirePath: `.//*[@id='confirmForm']/div/div[3]/div/label` unfortunately that doesnt work either.  I'll work my way through the rest of your post

Comment: Did you look for frame/iframe?? And make sure located id is unique and fixed

Comment: @tarquin And instead of implicit wait try with explicit wait using WebDriverWait instead as suggested and let me know..

Comment: I havent tried the iframe yet because I am not sure what I am doing I havent used this tool much.  The html code for the iframe is :  '<iframe id="d2l_1_69_954" class="d2l-iframe d2l-iframe-fullscreen d2l_1_67_746" name="d2l_1_69_954" src="/d2l/lms/remoteplugins/lti/launchLti.d2l?ou=6606&pluginId=f8acc58b-c6d5-42df-99d9-e334f825c011&d2l_body_type=3" title="TALLPOD" scrolling="auto" allowfullscreen="" onload="this.m_loaded=true;" style="height: 314px;" frameborder="0">' how do you locate this iframe using your example above?

Comment: Hmm, here looks like iframe id and name both are dynamically generated which could be change every time when you locate, you should try to locate this iframe with unique locator, I think it's title name is unique and fixed so you should try to locate this iframe before locating desired element as `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe[title='TAFEPOC']"));` and let me know

Comment: @tarquin I have edited it with provided answer as well, try it and let me know

Comment: Hi Saurabh thanks for your help.  I did try your suggestion but i get the following:  'Expected condition failed: waiting for frame to be available: By.cssSelector: if??rame[title='TAFEPOC'??]'

Comment: It looks like copy paste issue, try to type it manually, some extra characters appending like `??` remove it

Comment: @tarquin Copy it from provided edited answer instead of comments and try..

Comment: I managed to get the iframe found by using: 'wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'd2l_1_69')]")));'

Comment: I am still trying to figure out why selenium cannot find the checkbox using: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='confirmForm']/div/div[3]/div/label")).click();`  when i use the FirePath tool on mozilla I use the inspect element tool to generate the xpath of the checkbox.  This generated the xpath: `.//*[@id='confirmForm']/div/div[3]/div/label` but when I refresh the page & select the iframe & search for the xpath the check box doesnt get highlighted is weird.  But when I use the inspect element tool & click the checkbox the xpath generated is the same one that didnt work after page refresh

Comment: @tarquin And what happens when you trying to automate it using selenium script??